# OpenLayers + Liferay Portlet

Tags: javascript, liferay, openlayers, portlet

I'm new to Liferay and Portlet development and I'm trying to show an OpenLayers map in a portlet but without success.

Here is my view.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/liferay-ui" prefix='liferay-ui' %>
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.PortletPreferences" %>
<script src="http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/lib/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<p>My Map</p>

<div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
        "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'} );
    map.addLayer(wms);
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
</script>
```

The map is assigned to the div but just isn't displayed. Does anyone know why? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wild guess: Are you sure that there's only one id="map" on the page? I'd rather go for

```
<div ... id="<portlet:namespace/>map">
 ... var map = new OpenLayers.Map('<portlet:namespace/>map');
```